# Database Designing Problem?

Tags: database-design

We are working on a site, where we have products and their specifications. Products' data are stored in products table.

We are not sure how to store the specifications. As specifications for a refrigerator are completely different from the microwave or washing machine.

Can somebody suggest the other related tables that I can create to store the specifications?

Comment: are you thinking of filtering based on specification?

Comment: Yes that is also the case. But at this point of time just want to figure out the right way of storing information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like I asked the correct implementation depends on how you use the data.. If you dont want to query your specifications and you dont want much overhead to deal with then you can dump the specifications as part of a blob column in the Products table but that means you cant do anything with the data on the datbase end and have to act on the data once you read it into your web server or possibly use some kind of a full text search engine like the one discussed here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345119(v=sql.90).aspx

Otherwise you can probably store it as a key value pair with a foreign key mapped to each of the rows and you can even do your filtering in this case on the key and joining on the products table.

your table stucture in this case will be

```
Specifications:
Product_id,
Speecification_Name,
Specification_value (nvarchar),
Specification_type(string) // identifies the datatype of the value..  not sure how useful this is at this moment but smthing that you can consider while filtering
```

Answer (score 1):

The "correct" way to do this really depends on what you need to do with the data.  For example, let's say that the Microwave and Washing Machine both have "Wattage" as a specification.  Do you ever envision that you need to query all appliances by range of Wattage?  If so, you will need to store it as a table column with a numeric type.  If you don't need to do so, then a simple "key-value" table with two character columns (along with a product id) would be a good start.